# Attempt to read property "match_name" on null laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have

> ErrorException
> Attempt to read property "match_name" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Cbangla\resources\views\admin\manage\score\index.blade.php)
> Error

I want to fetch all data from my score tables This is my scores table database view

[image]

To fetch, all data from the scores table This is what I have in my ScoreController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $data=Score::all();
    $team=Team::all();
    $match=Matchh::all();
    $player=Player::all();

    return view('admin.manage.score.index',compact('data','team','match','player'));
}
```

This is my Score.php model

```
protected $fillable = ['score_name','score_slug','team_id','match_id','player_id'];

    public function team(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
    public function matchh(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Matchh::class);
    }
    public function playre(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
    }
```

This is my index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $row)
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->score_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->score_slug }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->matchh->match_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->team->team_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->player->player_name }}</td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `match_id` to `matchh` relationship case the name of your relationship is different than the match id you stored in database

```
 public function matchh(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Matchh::class,'match_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see, there is problem when score has not match or match not found.
First of all, you have to specify relation column, because your model is named `Matchh` and laravel is looking for `matchh_id` column.

#### Solution:

```
# Score.php model
public function matchh(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Matchh::class,'match_id');
}
```

#### Tip 1:

**You can use `optional` function, when you're not sure if model has relation or not**

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $row)
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->score_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $row->score_slug }}</td>
       <td>{{ optional($row->matchh)->match_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ optional($row->team)->team_name }}</td>
       <td>{{ optional($row->player)->player_name }}</td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

#### Tip 2:

**You can use `whereHas` function to be sure that `Score` has `Matchh`**

```
public function index()
{
    $data=Score::query()->whereHas('matchh')->get();
    $team=Team::all();
    $match=Matchh::all();
    $player=Player::all();

    return view('admin.manage.score.index',compact('data','team','match','player'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide key in relation because your method name is `matchh` and in that case relation except `matchh_id` but in you case it must be `match_id`.
So:

```php
public function matchh(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Matchh::class, 'match_id');
}
```